# Confused about differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, radicals

Suppose when solving a differential equation, you get to the stage $\frac{t^4}{4}=ln|x|+c$. Is it valid to then arrive at $t=\sqrt{2}(ln|x|+c)^\frac{1}{4}$? The graph of $y^4=x^4$ is not the same as that of $y=x$, so why is it valid to take the fourth root of both sides in the DE solution?

Comment: That depends on a variety of things.  Normally, with "x" a position and "t" time, x is a function of t and you would solve for x, not t ($x= e^{t^4/4- c}$).  "t" here is NOT a  function of x.  Yes, there are four possible values for x, two real, $t= \sqrt{2](ln|x|+ c)^{1/4}$ and $t= -\sqrt{2}(ln|x|+ c)^{1/4}$, the other two complex.